# What are the events Ember.js supports?

Tags: ember.js

I couldn't find this documented anywhere or answered in any question.  The only one I know for certain exists is 'click' (via [Handling events with action](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_handling-events-with-action)).

Related questions I've seen (which don't answer my question):

- [Ember events other than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237741/ember-events-other-than-click)
- [Using Ember.js, how do I run some JS after a view is rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881040/using-ember-js-how-do-i-run-some-js-after-a-view-is-rendered)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The supported event names are listed in http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html. Just search for "Possible events names":

**Touch events**: 'touchStart', 'touchMove', 'touchEnd', 'touchCancel'

**Keyboard events**: 'keyDown', 'keyUp', 'keyPress'

**Mouse events**: 'mouseDown', 'mouseUp', 'contextMenu', 'click', 'doubleClick', 'mouseMove', 'focusIn', 'focusOut', 'mouseEnter', 'mouseLeave'

**Form events**: 'submit', 'change', 'focusIn', 'focusOut', 'input'

**HTML5 drag and drop events**: 'dragStart', 'drag', 'dragEnter', 'dragLeave', 'drop', 'dragEnd'

Comment: it is a broken link

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a list in the source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js#L32-60) as well

Comment: This would be a more helpful answer if it explained how to get the list in the source rather than being link only; this link has changed (and may likely change again) meaning it is not a very useful link for the future.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, I just want to list here.

From `ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js`

List:

```
  events: {
    touchstart  : 'touchStart',
    touchmove   : 'touchMove',
    touchend    : 'touchEnd',
    touchcancel : 'touchCancel',
    keydown     : 'keyDown',
    keyup       : 'keyUp',
    keypress    : 'keyPress',
    mousedown   : 'mouseDown',
    mouseup     : 'mouseUp',
    contextmenu : 'contextMenu',
    click       : 'click',
    dblclick    : 'doubleClick',
    mousemove   : 'mouseMove',
    focusin     : 'focusIn',
    focusout    : 'focusOut',
    mouseenter  : 'mouseEnter',
    mouseleave  : 'mouseLeave',
    submit      : 'submit',
    input       : 'input',
    change      : 'change',
    dragstart   : 'dragStart',
    drag        : 'drag',
    dragenter   : 'dragEnter',
    dragleave   : 'dragLeave',
    dragover    : 'dragOver',
    drop        : 'drop',
    dragend     : 'dragEnd'
  },
```