# Ember.js: How do I hook Ember.CollectionView after every child view is rendered?

Tags: javascript, dom, ember.js

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881040/using-ember-js-how-do-i-run-some-js-after-a-view-is-rendered) demonstrates that overriding an Ember.View instance's `didInsertElement` allows you to execute some code after the view's element is in the DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/gvUux/2/

Naturally, overriding `didInsertElement` on the child view class you add to an Ember.CollectionView will run the hook after each child view is rendered and inserted.

http://jsfiddle.net/BFUvK/1/

Two collection-oriented hooks on Ember.CollectionView, `arrayDidChange` and `contentDidChange`, execute after the underlying content has changed, but they execute before any rendering takes place. `arrayDidChange` is executed for every element added to the array, and `contentDidChange` wraps the content binding.

I would like to be able to hook around the rendering pipeline, something like `willInsertCollection` and `didInsertCollection`, to manipulate the DOM before and after all child elements are rendered - essentially, before and after filters around `contentBinding`.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to want to do something before and/or after a view has been rendered you should use `willInsertElement` and/or `didInsertElement` respectively. In this case, since you want "to manipulate the DOM before and after all child elements are rendered" you should call those on your CollectionView.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "before and after filters around `contentBinding`", so if this doesn't answer your question if you could clarify I'd be happy to help.

[jsFiddle if needed](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/NFDqW/)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I'm afraid, though, that the CollectionView `didInsertElement` hook is fired _before_ each added child's version of `didInsertElement`, [here's a modified example.](http://jsfiddle.net/NFDqW/5/)

I think I can find a workaround, but I'm still trying to find the right pattern for collections that gives me what I'm looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: That modification you made is in the CollectionView's ItemView and yes that will fire before each added child's version. Can you be more specific about what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've update the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/NFDqW/) to do exactly what you were trying to do just within the CollectionView instead of the ItemView.

Comment: Thanks, I see it working now in jsFiddle. I have an exact copy of this behavior in an application, though, and it has the opposite behavior - the collectionView's `didInsertElement` fires when IT is added to the DOM, not when any child elements are added. I can't say I know why. In any case, I'll mark this as accepted. I thank you for your help!

Comment: I've updated that fiddle again. Sounds like you need to manipulate the runloop here (still curious what exactly you're trying to do). The runloop is an interesting beast... I won't go too much into how it works here, but hopefully the code explains enough. Also, take a look at the [runloop's source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/run_loop.js), specifically the Ember.run.* functions.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to apply a scroll animation to slide a list up after pushing new objects. The list was rendered using an ArrayController and the `#each` helper. Simply triggering an event on the controller which the view subscribed to after pushing objects was causing the animation to execute before the changes to the content were actually rendered. The following technique worked perfectly for me.

```
//excerpt from my loadMore method on the ArrayController

var self = this;
self.content.pushObjects(moreItems);
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function()
{
  self.trigger('loadMoreComplete');
});
```